# Cannot run a JavaFX project with OpenJDK10

Tags: java, javafx

I've been getting into JavaFX lately and it worked fine with the Oracle JDK but I can't make it run on OpenJDK 10. This is what I've done so far:

- Installed OpenJDK and set it up in IntelliJ
- Downloaded JavaFX SDK 10 and added the library as well
- I'm using the OpenJDK as JRE

It compiles just fine but every time I try to run the application I get:

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

Building and running it as a Maven project does not make a difference. However, if I install the Oracle JRE 10 and make the project run on it, it works. I'm on Windows by the way.

Comment: *and added the library as well* - added it where?

Comment: under libraries in the intelliJ project settings and it compiled just fine. Also tried Maven.

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52654791/6395627) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52571719/6395627). Those answers deal with JavaFX 11 (and a slightly different issue) but the core cause is the same as for your issue, I believe.