# Missing JavaFX runtime components when running .jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx

I'm trying to build a standalone .jar using Intellij that includes JavaFX, however I get following error when trying to run it.  .

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application
```

I've followed the advice from this question [Trying to run executable jar of JavaFX app - Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53754275/trying-to-run-executable-jar-of-javafx-app-error-javafx-runtime-components-ar)
  and I can run the jar successfully. But I'd like to be able to run it without needing to specify the VM arguments if possible (so it works on a different PC).

So my question is is it possible to include the `JavaFX` classes in the `.jar` file so I can run this application anywhere that has java installed? Or am I going to need to install `JavaFX` then make a script to run the `.jar` with the correct VM arguments pointing to `JavaFX`?

I'm not using a build system such as `gradle` or `maven` with this project, I'm downloading the `JavaFX` files and including them as libraries from Intellij.

[Screenshot of my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBCwz.jpg)

Comment: As far as I know, your client computers would need the Java runtime installed, along with JavaFX, in order for the JAR to "just work."