# Error: JavaFX runtime component is missing and needs to be used to run this application

Tags: java, java-11, javafx-17

jdk:17.0.8  Mave:3.8.8

- I want to use GraalVM to package the native image, see [GraalVM website](https://www.graalvm.org/latest/reference-manual/native-image/guides/build-native-executable-from-jar/)
  Use the "native image-jar App.jar" command easy to generate a native image.
  The premise is that need to build JavaFX programs as executable jar files.
- Follow the [JavaFX guide](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#maven)  to build using the "javafx-maven-plugin",But it builds out a zip, not a jar file.
- Then I tried to build with "maven-jar-plugin" and "maven-assembly-plugin"  plugins, which were able to output the executable jar file, but both had the same problem when executing :Error: JavaFX runtime component is missing and needs to be used to run this application
- The problem is the same as  [his](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54319825/missing-javafx-runtime-components-when-running-jar)
- My goal is to use GraalVM to build a nativa image of JavaFX.   What is the best way to do this

the code is IntelliJ IDEA auto generate,use IntelliJ IDEA run is normal

```java
public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(HelloApplication.class.getResource("hello-view.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load(), 320, 240);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```