# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/reactivex/subjects/Subject when building jar in Intellij Idea (gradle + JavaFX 11)

Tags: java, gradle, rx-java2, javafx-11, openfx

I am running some app with JavaFX 11 (OpenFX). The app is written in IntellijIdea and built with gradle. When running in IDE everything's ok. When building a jar it builds successfully but when I try to execute it I get an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/reactivex/subjects/Subject
```

To build a jar I use onslip.gradle-one-jar plugin. My gradle is the following:

```
plugins {
   id 'application'
   id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.5'
   id 'com.github.onslip.gradle-one-jar' version '1.0.5'
}

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-base:11:win"
   implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:11:win"
   implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-controls:11:win"
   implementation "org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:11:win"
   implementation 'com.jfoenix:jfoenix:9.0.8' 
   implementation group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.6' 
   implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6' 
   implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.141.59' 
   implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.8.1' 
   implementation group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'javax.mail', version: '1.6.2' 
   implementation group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2', name: 'rxjava', version: '2.2.5' 
   testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

javafx {
   modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

mainClassName = 'jetliner.Main'

jar {
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'jetliner.Main'
    }
}

task awesomeFunJar(type: OneJar) {
    mainClass = 'jetliner.Main'
}
```

For jar building I run awesomeFunJar task.

Comment: How do you try to launch it?

Comment: I run awesomeFunJar task which executes build function from com.github.onslip.gradle-one-jar plugin

Comment: Ok for building, but when you say "when I try to execute it"?

Comment: In IDE finder I press right-click on built jar file, then select run.

Comment: There is something strange because your gradle file defines `mainClassName = 'jetliner.Main'`, but the run action seems willing to launch the `io/reactivex/subjects/Subject` one, maybe there is something wrong in your launcher configuration?

Comment: In my main class (jetliner.Main) I import `import io.reactivex.subjects.Subject` and call `subject = PublishSubject.create();` So, as I guess the jar is not packed properly and gives this exception because cannot import this class from external library `io.reactivex.rxjava2`

Comment: Yes it is certainly the case; so you should update your gradle file to package third party libraries within yours.

Comment: José answer is just perfect; he was quicker than me ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem you have in your build is related to how you define the dependencies with `implementation` (not `compile` anymore), while on the other hand, you build your jar based on `configurations.compile`.

Since `implementation` and `compile` are not the same, `configurations.compile` contains only the classes of your project, not the third party dependencies (including JavaFX).

Running the build task will generate a very small fat jar of 3 KB. Obviously this jar misses all the classes from the dependencies.

**Solution**

Replace in your jar task `configurations.compile` with `configurations.compileClasspath`:

```
jar {
    from { configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'jetliner.Main'
    }
}
```

Run `./gradlew build` to generate a fat jar (around 23 MB with the given dependencies), that can be run with:

```
java -jar build/libs/myproject.jar
```

Or run `./gradlew awesomeFunJar` to produce a similar fat jar (21 MB), that runs with:

```
java -jar build/libs/myproject-standalone.jar
```

In both cases, the `io.reactivex.rxjava2` dependencies are included.

**Note 1**: I haven't used this gradle-one-jar plugin before, and I don't see any major advantage in having the custom loader, all I see is that for a helloFX sample takes really too long to load it compare with the regular fat jar.

If you use it because the fat jar doesn't run, maybe you need a `Launcher` class, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52571719/3956070):

```
public class Launcher {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main.main(args);
    }
}
```

and then replace the mainClass with `jetliner.Launcher`.

**Note 2**: The JavaFX plugin (latest version 0.0.7) uses `implementation`, and it takes care of adding the JavaFX dependencies, so you can simplify the build file:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.7'
    id 'com.github.onslip.gradle-one-jar' version '1.0.5'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.jfoenix:jfoenix:9.0.8'
    implementation group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.6'
    implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
    implementation group: 'org.seleniumhq.selenium', name: 'selenium-java', version: '3.141.59'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.8.1'
    implementation group: 'com.sun.mail', name: 'javax.mail', version: '1.6.2'
    implementation group: 'io.reactivex.rxjava2', name: 'rxjava', version: '2.2.5'
    testImplementation group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}

javafx {
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

mainClassName = 'jetliner.Launcher'

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'jetliner.Launcher'
    }
    from {
        configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}

task awesomeFunJar(type: OneJar) {
    mainClass = 'jetliner.Main'
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Using the gradle you have provided in Note 2 I have successfully built and executed jar. The only small remark is that `mainClassName = 'jetliner.Launcher'` is needed to be kept, otherwise the app will not run with `./gradlew run`

Comment: Yes, right, I missed to paste it, sorry. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error while executing the extend `Reports.java`, I have rectified it.
I simply imported the  `rxjava3.jar` and `reactive.jar` into the project.
It resolved my error

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).