# JavaFX eclipse configuration - openJDK 10

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

I'm trying to configuring JavaFX project in eclipse 2018-12 (4.10.0). I installed openJDK 10 and e(fx)clipse plugin.

I can create javaFX project no problem with that. But, when I tried to execute that project I got this error:

[image]

Any help please!

----- Edit -----

```
Error: JavaFX runtime components that are required to run this application are missing.
```

Comment: english, please? we could bearly understand the error. Would you mind translating that to English?

Comment: Sorry for that, I added the translation

Answer (score 0):

There is a thread pointing to the same [issue](https://github.com/javafxports/openjdk-jfx/issues/236) as yours(OpenJDK 10) and for OpenJDK 11 [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52653836/maven-shade-javafx-runtime-components-are-missing/52654791#52654791) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569724/javafx-11-create-a-jar-file-with-gradle/52571719#52571719) may be good pointers.

Answer (score 0):

JavaFX, as you may already know is no longer included in the JDK (this is to include OpenJDK as well). JavaFX's project website explains how to correctly add the JavaFX SDK (or jmods) and to configure them to work with Eclipse.

See [here](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) for the JavaFX getting started guide for Eclipse setup.

Their website goes into detail on the very error that you are receiving, and states how to resolve it. I will leave you with the [link](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) in case any of this changes in future releases.

[image: JavaFX11: Missing module error]

If you are trying to use JavaFX11 with JDK 10, I don't think that will be possible. See below from JavaFX (openjfx.io) website.

[image]

Comment: yes, I saw that and it works fine for openJDK 11 and openjfx 11. But, I need to use openJDK 10 (not 11) so I don't know how should I configure JavaFX with openJDK 10.

Comment: Apologies, didn't notice that you had said JDK 10. I have edited my original answer.

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't solve the problem ! I tried to build javaFX project using openjdk 10 and openjfx 11. It works fine only If I'm using --module-path <path-to>/javafx-sdk-11/lib   --add modules=javafx.controls

Comment: Have you added the JavaFX jars to your eclipse project?

Comment: yes I installed e(fx)clipse plugin into my eclipse and the jfxrt.jar is well added to my project and I have no problem when I build it. But when I try to execute it, I need to indicate the path of javafx sdk to my run configuration arguments