# Gradle build jar file with JavaFX components can't find main class

Tags: java, gradle, javafx, build.gradle, manifest

I'm trying to create a jar-file for my JavaFX project but I cant't seem to get it to work. Depending on what I do I get a mix of two different errors:
`Error: Could not find or load main class mapsRUs.MapsRUs` & `Error: JavaFX runtime components are missing, and are required to run this application`. With this configuration it's the first of the two.

My build.gradle looks like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.7'
}

javafx {
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml' ]
}

applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-Xmx4g"]

mainClassName = 'mapsRUs.MapsRUs'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'

    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.3.2'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.3.2'

    // Use JUnit test framework
    testCompileOnly 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.vintage:junit-vintage-engine:5.3.1'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jar {
    baseName = "Maps R Us"
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': mainClassName
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

The manifest file generated by the jar-task looks like this:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: mapsRUs.MapsRUs
```

My main class includes this (it has some more things unimportant to this topic):

```
public class MapsRUs extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ... some code ...
    }
```

Can anyone figure out what is wrong here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Read the [highest voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52571719/6395627), especially the part about using a main class that doesn't extend `Application`.

Comment: Thanks, I had tried that but with some other settings - tried it now and it worked! Thanks a lot.