# Java 12 and JavaFX 12 - create runnable jar and custom JRE

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, javafx-11

I am trying to adapt my program to run with Java 12.  It currently runs with Java 8 and has some JavaFX components (a few dialogs).  It's not modular.  My IDE is Eclipse, and the JavaFX jar files are included in the build path as a User Library.  I'd like to generate a runnable jar and either bundle the javafx files inside or add them to the custom JRE, so that I can distribute it without requiring the end user to have Java12 or JavaFX installed separately.

To start, I thought I'd experiment with a simple [HelloFX](https://github.com/openjfx/samples/blob/master/HelloFX/CLI/hellofx/HelloFX.java) program modified to more closely resemble my program.

```
public class HelloFX2 {

    public HelloFX2() {
        startToolkit();

        // have to wait a second for the JavaFX thread to actually start, or else the Platform.runLater throws an exception
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }

        // create the scene and display
        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            Scene theScene = createTheScene();
            final Stage stage = new Stage();
            stage.setScene(theScene);
            stage.show();
        });

    }

    public Scene createTheScene() {
        String javaVersion = System.getProperty("java.version");
        String javafxVersion = System.getProperty("javafx.version");
        Label l = new Label("Hello, JavaFX " + javafxVersion + ", running on Java " + javaVersion + ".");
        Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane(l), 640, 480);
        return scene;
    }

    public void startToolkit () {
        // we can only create a Scene in a JavaFX thread
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {

            // Initialize FX Toolkit, so that we can use the Java FX objects
            new JFXPanel();
        });
    }

}
```

I also used a Main class to run, as per [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52569724/javafx-11-create-a-jar-file-with-gradle).  I don't think I need it in my case because HelloFX2 doesn't extend `Application`, but again this is closer to what my actual program looks like.

```
public class Main2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HelloFX2 theApp = new HelloFX2();
    }
}
```

The program runs fine in Eclipse.  I export as a runnable JAR file with the 'Extract Libraries' option, and then use the `jdeps` and `jlink` to create a custom JRE:

```
D:\Work\Java12>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin\jdeps" --ignore-missing-deps --print-module-deps HelloFX2.jar
java.base,java.desktop

D:\Work\Java12>"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin\jlink" --no-header-files --no-man-pages  --add-modules java.base,java.desktop --output java-runtime
```

But when I try to run it, I get this error:

```
D:\Work\Java12>"java-runtime\bin\java" -jar HelloFX2.jar
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  d3d, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:243)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:260)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
        at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.lambda$initFx$1(JFXPanel.java:224)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
        ... 1 more
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:272)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
        at javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel.lambda$initFx$1(JFXPanel.java:224)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835)
```

This is the same error that occurs with the original HelloFX program when you don't add the --module-path switch to the command line, but I shouldn't need that because I don't extend `Application`.

Is JavaFX not being found?  The JavaFX class files are all included in the jar, but I'm not sure how to point to them.

Comment: It looks like your fat jar only contains the JavaFX classes, but not the native libraries that are part of the JavaFX SDK.

Comment: That did it!  I copied all the dll files to a lib64 folder, and used `"java-runtime6\bin\java" -Djava.library.path=lib64 -jar HelloFX2.jar` to run.  If you post this as a solution I can mark it as solved

Comment: Done, posted the answer.

Comment: Texts and docs not worked for me! I read the sample code and got it .. this is the [link](https://github.com/openjfx/samples)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the JavaFX SDK, there is a `lib` folder with the jars like `javafx.base.jar`, or `javafx.controls.jar`, but also there are native libraries like `libglass.so` (Linux), `libglass.dylib`(Mac). On Windows, the native dlls, like `glass.dll`are in the `bin` folder.

When packaging those classes into a fat jar, you must take into account the required native libraries too.

This means that you have to pack the native libraries for `javafx.graphics`, but you don't need to include the webkit library (that adds around 80 MB) if you don't use the `javafx.web` module.

Note also that these libraries are platform specific (and even the jars). In case you want to distribute your jar to other platforms, you can also pack the classes and native libraries from those platforms, simply by downloading the SDK for them.

All of this is explained in detail in https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular, section Non-modular project - Command Line.

For modular projects, `jlink` is the recommended tool. In both cases, also using build tools (Gradle/Maven) really helps dealing with the JavaFX dependencies: you won't need the JavaFX SDK, as you will retrieve the dependencies from Maven Central, and these already bundle the native libraries with them. Again, worth reading the whole https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#modular document.

Comment: simply by downloading the SDK for them, what do you mean?

Comment: If you work with the JavaFX SDK, you have to get it from here: https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/, choosing OS, version and architecture. I meant that you have to download different SDKs for different platforms.