# Run Groovy at the CLI with Java 9+ module settings

Tags: java, javafx, groovy, java-11, java-module

OS: Linux Mint 18.3
The combo I want to run is: Groovy 3.0.+ (app and testing code) & Java 11+ & JavaFX 11+

Having had a little help (see comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60591754/595305)) I can now do this using a gradle.build file (including outputting an executable using the Gradle "installDist" task from the `application` plugin).

I've also managed to do this from a non-Gradle Groovy-enabled project in IntelliJ, by configuring the classpath and module-path appropriately.

My file javaFXTest.groovy looks like this (NB this is the Groovy script which I get IntelliJ to run):

```
package core

import javafx.application.Application
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader
import javafx.scene.Parent
import javafx.scene.Scene
import javafx.stage.Stage

Application.launch(  GrApp, args)

class GrApp extends Application {

    @Override
    void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/dialog1.fxml"))       
        primaryStage.title = "Hello World"
        primaryStage.scene = new Scene(root, 1200, 800)
        primaryStage.show()
    }
}
```

I'm just wondering, for the sake of interest, how this is actually done in terms of a CLI `groovy` command.  I thought it might be something like this:

```
groovy -cp .:/home/mike/.java/JavaFX/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/*  --module-path /home/mike/.java/JavaFX/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml core/javaFXTest.groovy
```

oops:

```
Caught: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/mike/IdeaProjects/JavaFXExp2/AppTest/src/main/groovy/--module-path (/home/mike/IdeaProjects/JavaFXExp2/AppTest/src/main/groovy/--module-path)
```

... it clearly doesn't recognise `--module-path` as a configurable option, confirmed by going `groovy --help`. I searched on this and found nothing. And yet IntelliJ manages to run this script: the `--module-path` and `--add-modules` options are added as VM options to the run configuration. Anyone know how this might be done as a CLI command?

Comment: What runner are you using in IntelliJ? If you just run this with the gradle runner (an option under Gradle/Runner IIRC), then it just does that.  Otherwise it tries to it's best to mimic what gradle would do (this sometimes fails horrible). If you are lucky intellij shows the full command at the beginning of the log output (it's some different color and folded aways).  In your CLI example I am sceptical about the non-quoted `*`

Comment: I've only been using IntelliJ for a week or so (fugitive from Eclipse), so I don't know about runners. The project where I ran this started as a JavaFX project with Groovy added in. Just going to fire up and see whether I can see the full command...

Answer (score 0):

On the suggestion by cfrick I found the answer: Intellij does indeed show the whole command in the "Run" view (if you click the '...'):

Turns out this is a giant Java command with all sorts of stuff beyond my understanding, and inclusion of many Groovy .jars for example. I show it in its magnificence for anyone interested: I've split up into lines to show the options a bit more clearly.

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.11.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java 
-Dgroovy.home=/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2 
-Dgroovy.starter.conf=/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/conf/groovy-starter.conf 
-javaagent:/home/mike/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/201.6073.9/lib/idea_rt.jar=41350:/home/mike/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/IDEA-C/ch-0/201.6073.9/bin 
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 
-classpath /home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-3.0.2.jar org.codehaus.groovy.tools.GroovyStarter 
--conf /home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/conf/groovy-starter.conf 
--main groovy.ui.GroovyMain 
--classpath .:/home/mike/IdeaProjects/JavaFXExp2/out/production/AppTest:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-test-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-yaml-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/junit-platform-launcher-1.6.0.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/junit-jupiter-api-5.6.0.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/junit-jupiter-engine-5.6.0.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-templates-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-groovysh-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/jsp-api-2.0.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/ant-1.10.7.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.10.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/javaparser-core-3.15.13.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-json-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/ant-launcher-1.10.7.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-xml-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-testng-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-jmx-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-dateutil-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/junit-4.13.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/xstream-1.4.11.1.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/ivy-2.5.0.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-servlet-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/gpars-1.2.1.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/jcommander-1.72.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/jsr166y-1.7.0.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/ant-antlr-1.10.7.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/multiverse-core-0.7.0.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-jsr223-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-sql-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-groovydoc-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/bsf-2.4.0.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/org.abego.treelayout.core-1.0.1.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/jackson-core-2.10.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/ST4-4.1.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-console-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/jackson-annotations-2.10.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/jansi-1.18.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-datetime-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-astbuilder-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-jaxb-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-ant-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-test-junit5-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-swing-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/qdox-1.12.1.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-cli-picocli-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-cli-commons-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-macro-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-nio-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/junit-platform-engine-1.6.0.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/junit-platform-commons-1.6.0.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/testng-6.14.3.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/jackson-databind-2.10.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/ant-junit-1.10.7.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/opentest4j-1.2.0.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-bsf-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/commons-cli-1.4.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/snakeyaml-1.24.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/jline-2.14.6.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/groovy-docgenerator-3.0.2.jar:/home/mike/.java/JavaFX/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/src.zip:/home/mike/.java/JavaFX/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx-swt.jar:/home/mike/.java/JavaFX/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.web.jar:/home/mike/.java/JavaFX/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.base.jar:/home/mike/.java/JavaFX/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.fxml.jar:/home/mike/.java/JavaFX/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.media.jar:/home/mike/.java/JavaFX/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.swing.jar:/home/mike/.java/JavaFX/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.controls.jar:/home/mike/.java/JavaFX/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib/javafx.graphics.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/extras-jaxb/jaxb-api-2.3.0.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/extras-jaxb/activation-1.1.1.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/extras-jaxb/jaxb-core-2.3.0.1.jar:/home/mike/.sdkman/candidates/groovy/3.0.2/lib/extras-jaxb/jaxb-impl-2.3.0.1.jar 

--encoding=UTF-8 
/home/mike/IdeaProjects/JavaFXExp2/AppTest/src/main/groovy/core/javaFXTest.groovy
```

I hazard a guess that the first `-classpath` option (with the single dash) is presumably setting that for the "javaagent"... or could it be for the "Groovy starter"...?

This at least solves the conundrum: I had understood that Groovy (even Groovy 3) can't handle Java 9+ modules. So it would make sense that this must be a Java command.  Maybe running with a `groovy` commmand will become possible with Groovy 4, which as I understand it will (hopefully) be able to be able to handle these modules.